# Trying to save/load image in app error NSInvalidArgumentException

Tags: xcode, load, directory, save

Im  trying to save and load an image picked from camera roll within my app.  I get an error when I press either the load or save button

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView CGImage]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe637640'

any thoughts?

AppDelagate .m

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory i       nDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

.m of class im trying to save/load image

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {
UIImage *myImage = imageView;
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appDocsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];


}

- (IBAction)load:(id)sender {
UIImage *myImage = imageView;
NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appDocsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage* thumImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png", appDocsDirectory, @"myNewFile"]];
}
```

Comment: My initial thoughts are that you haven't tagged the question properly and you haven't included a stacktrace.

Comment: You don't seem to want to help yourself.  Your tags are wrong; they are all irrelevent (someone could correct them, but then why should they?).  If you don't tag the question correctly then the right person is likely to miss it.  In cases of exception/crash it's critical to have a stack trace in order to pinpoint where the issue lies.  So if you want help you need to provide better information.

Comment: Are you still on this? go and bother someone else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error means that message CGImage is sent to object of type UIImageView, but UIImageView does not response to it. The problem is seemed to be in

```
UIImage *myImage = imageView;
```

You do not write properly implementation of imageView, so I can not say exactly, but I assume that imageView is UIImageView, which is subclass of UIView, and you are assigning it to UIImage. Try

```
UIImage *myImage = [imageView image];
```

instead. I think that should works))

by the way, why do you need first and second strings of code in -load? They are unnecessary:

```
- (IBAction)load:(id)sender {
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *appDocsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage* thumImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png", appDocsDirectory, @"myNewFile"]];
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that has stopped the exception being thrown and I have got rid of the two redundant lines of code, thanks for pointing that out and for your help.  Now I just have to get the image to save and load!